How to observe a change in Android aws amplify from backend in dynamodb?
I have created a mobile app for aws amplify with android apmlify. My requirement is to observe the real time changes in the dynamo db or directly through the scripts from any other app or directly on the console.
When I add some data from my mobile client it gets added to the dynamo db and it returns the changed data to my observe method, but when someone changes or edits the data directly into the console I am not able to observe it.How to do it ? My code is as follows
 package com.example.appsyncdynamodb

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.model.ModelQuery
import com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.model.ModelSubscription
import com.amplifyframework.core.Action
import com.amplifyframework.core.Amplify
import com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer
import com.amplifyframework.core.async.Cancelable
import com.amplifyframework.core.model.query.ObserveQueryOptions
import com.amplifyframework.core.model.query.predicate.QueryPredicate
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.DataStoreException
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.DataStoreItemChange
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.DataStoreQuerySnapshot
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.generated.model.Todo

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        Amplify.DataStore.start({},
        {})
        val btn:Button = findViewById(R.id.btn)
        var i : Int=0
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            i += 1;
            Log.d("printed inside","inside")

            //your implementation goes here
            val item = Todo.builder()
                .name("Todo").description("Hello Vibhor")
                .build()

            Amplify.DataStore.save(item,
                { Log.i("Tutorial", "Saved item: ${item.toString()}") },
                { Log.e("Tutorial", "Could not save item to DataStore", it) }
            )
        }
        Log.d("printed outside","outside")


        val subscription = Amplify.API.subscribe(
            ModelSubscription.onUpdate(Todo::class.java),
            { Log.d("ApiQuickStart", "Subscription established") },
            { Log.d("ApiQuickStart", "Todo update subscription received:$it") },
            { Log.d("ApiQuickStart", "Subscription failed", it) },
            { Log.d("ApiQuickStart", "Subscription completed") }
        )

        Amplify.DataStore.observe(Todo::class.java,
            { Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Observation began") },
            {
                val post = it.item()
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    Toast.makeText(this, it.item().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                Log.i("MyAmplifyAppobs", "Post: $post")
            },
            { Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Observation failed", it) },
            { Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Observation complete") }
        )

        val subscription2 = Amplify.API.subscribe(
            ModelSubscription.onCreate(Todo::class.java),
            { Log.d("ApiQuickStart", "Subscription established") },
            { Log.d("ApiQuickStart", "Todo create subscription received:$it") },
            { Log.d("ApiQuickStart", "Subscription failed", it) },
            { Log.d("ApiQuickStart", "Subscription completed") }
        )

        val tag = "ObserveQuery"
        val onQuerySnapshot: Consumer<DataStoreItemChange<Todo>> =
            Consumer<DataStoreItemChange<Todo>> { value: DataStoreItemChange<Todo> ->
                Log.d(tag, "success on snapshot")
                Log.d(tag, "records: $value")
                //Log.d(tag, "number of records: " + value.items.size)
                //Log.d(tag, "sync status: " + value.isSynced)
            }

        val observationStarted =
            Consumer { _: Cancelable ->
                Log.d(tag, "success on cancelable")
            }
        val onObservationError =
            Consumer { value: DataStoreException ->
                Log.d(tag, "error on snapshot $value")
            }
        val onObservationComplete = Action {
            Log.d(tag, "complete")
        }
       val predicate: QueryPredicate =
            Todo.NAME.beginsWith("Build")
//        val querySortBy = QuerySortBy("post", "rating", QuerySortOrder.ASCENDING)

//        val options = ObserveQueryOptions(predicate,null)
//        Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery(
//            Todo::class.java,
//            options,
//            observationStarted,
//            onQuerySnapshot,
//            onObservationError,
//            onObservationComplete
//        )


        Amplify.API.query(
            ModelQuery.list(Todo::class.java),
            { response ->
                response.data.forEach { todo ->
                    Log.i("Query++", todo.name)
                }
            },
            { Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Query failure", it) }
        )

        Amplify.DataStore.observe(
            {Log.d("Observe", "Observation started established")},
            {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    Toast.makeText(this, it.item().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                Log.d("item change", "item change"+it.item().toString())},
            {},
            {}
        )
    }
}


You cannot observe changes to items in DynamoDB that are not made through Amplify, not without reading it explicitly.

So how to do it real time ? Does javascript app have to do it from amplify ? Is it possible because I am not a js side developer. So I need some hint.

You want to get notified of changes made when using the AWS Console in your application?

No ideally there would be a backend app , where they would push a data and I need to observe it real time, dynamo db is not compulsory, but we were not getting any idea to do without dynamo db if it is possible.

Using Amplify Subscriptions: https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/graphqlapi/subscribe-data/
